# Is it possible to achieve lead scoring, personalisation / marketing automation using Craft?

Tags: plugins

Is there a Craft equivalent of this type of marketing automation?

- lead scoring
- personalisation

For example (4 min): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ck9ywjBTEGM

Is there any plugin or external service that can be used with Craft to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The best way will likely depend on your situation. This type of functionality will also require some amount of custom development and implementation time.

A few examples:

- Services like [Intercom](https://www.intercom.com) can be integrated into Craft. You would manage marketing automation via Intercom and the custom development necessary would be to tie in the actions of your users on your Craft site with Intercom so you had the data you need to communicate how you wish. Intercom can be integrated into login processes, track user actions, and capture data when users submit Forms (plugins like [Sprout Forms](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms) and Solspace [Freeform](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform) are both capable of being customized to integrate with third-party services).
- For more generic data capture, [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com) can capture a lot of data about your customers. Mixpanel is more of a data analytics platform, so using a service like this will require that you have a larger budget to build out your own marketing automation processes around the data you gather.
- For additional control over your transactional email in Craft, [Sprout Email](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email) can help with dynamic personalization of your email notifications, integration with custom events, and targeting specific lists of users.

In all of these cases, you will want to develop a clear plan around your requirements and budget time for customization to integrate the plugins and services into your sites workflows.